# Removing contents separated with - as line separator by searching a pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file containing the below input.

```
----------
          ID: alternatives_create_editor
    Function: alternatives.install
        Name: editor
      Result: None
     Comment: Alternative will be set for editor to /usr/bin/vim.basic with priority 100
     Started: 10:45:49.115459
    Duration: 0.78 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: hosts_1
    Function: host.present
        Name: ip6-allnodes
      Result: None
     Comment: Host ip6-allnodes (ff02::1) already present
     Started: 10:45:49.127667
    Duration: 1.117 ms
     Changes:

----------
          ID: sfrsyslog_fix_logrotate
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog is set to be changed
     Started: 10:45:50.771278
    Duration: 12.751 ms
     Changes:
----------
```

My goal is to remove the whole part where Comment: contains already present.

I tried, `grep -B 5 -A 4 'already present' FILE1 > FILE2`.

Then,

`diff -y FILE1 FILE2 | grep '<' | sed 's/`

In this output I am getting like below,

```
          ID: alternatives_create_editor
    Function: alternatives.install
        Name: editor
      Result: None
     Comment: Alternative will be set for editor to /usr/bin/
     Started: 10:45:49.115459
    Duration: 0.78 ms
     Changes:

----------
          ID: sfrsyslog_fix_logrotate
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog is set to be
     Started: 10:45:50.771278
    Duration: 12.751 ms
     Changes:
----------
```

Problem is the `Comment: section` is not giving whole complete line. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More straightforward is to use a single GNU awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="----------\n"};!/Comment:[^\n]*already present/' file
```

It simply sets the record separator as the ten-dash lines and if the record contains `Comment:[^\n]*already present`, it suppresses that record. `[^\n]*` means "not a newline character", so that it won't suppress the record if it has `already present` in `Changes:` but not in `Comment:`.

Output:

```
----------
          ID: alternatives_create_editor
    Function: alternatives.install
        Name: editor
      Result: None
     Comment: Alternative will be set for editor to /usr/bin/vim.basic with priority 100
     Started: 10:45:49.115459
    Duration: 0.78 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: sfrsyslog_fix_logrotate
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
      Result: None
     Comment: The file /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog is set to be changed
     Started: 10:45:50.771278
    Duration: 12.751 ms
     Changes:
----------
```

---

If you do not have GNU awk, the above may not work because POSIX does not define the behavior of a multi-character record separator. So I leave this portable alternative:

```
awk '/Comment:.*already present/{p=1}
    /^-{10}$/{
        if(p!=1){printf "%s",lines}
        p=0
        lines=""
    }
    {lines=lines $0 RS}
' file
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better with `/^\s*Comment:.*already present/`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics I fear not, because the RS was been altered.

Comment: Then how about `/\n\s*Comment:.*already present/`?

Comment: Thank you Quasímodo

Comment: @TrippKinetics I fail to see how this would improve it... Can you explain it?

Comment: It would prevent an `already present` in a field other than (and after) `Comment:` from being a false positive.

Comment: Like if one of the `Changes:` lines happened to contain `already present`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Thank you for calling my attention to that. But the regex you proposed would not solve it. I have edited the answer to cover that special case too

Comment: @TrippKinetics I see you have proposed editing `/Comment:[^\n]*already present/` for the POSIX solution but in that solution each line is read at a time, so it's safe to write it as it is now.

Comment: Very good.  Thanks/

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="----------\n"} $0 !~ /already present/' file
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the accepted answer. If anything, it’s less good.